# How to access in Git Bash a folder name with space and a hyphen?

Tags: bash

I want to access a folder with name in the format "Lorem - Ipsum" and I can not rename the folder.

I have tried with using

```
"Lorem\ - \ Ipsum"
```

and

```
"Lorem\-\Ipsum"
```

If this is already answered please point me to the answer. Thank you

Comment: Does the shell you're using have tab-completion? I find it more convenient than trying to type filenames like that. Your first example doesn't match because of upper- vs lower-case "L" and too many spaces after the hyphen. The second attempt doesn't match because there's no spaces at all. This should work: "Lorem - Ipsum". If you didn't want the quoted string, then you have to escape the spaces:  Lorem\ -\ Ipsum   Good luck!

Comment: Normally, you quote *or* escape special characters, not both. (There are exceptions, but they're probably not relevant here.)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. I was able to access the folder and learned two ways to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the folder, either quote the folder name (that is, surround the folder name, unchanged, with quotes):

```
cd "Lorem - Ipsum"
```

or escape white space (that is, prefix *every* white space character with a backslash (`\`)):

```
cd Lorem\ -\ Ipsum
```

but **don't mix them**.

Check the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) for more information on quoting.